# undefined method `prepend' for Searchkick::Query:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, web-deployment, searchkick

After adding gem searchkick to my Gemfile I get this error when I try to delpoy the project:

```
/home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/faraday-0.8.9/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:4 warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BOUNDARY
DEBUG[eff60d47]     rake aborted!
DEBUG[eff60d47]     NoMethodError: undefined method `prepend' for Searchkick::Query:Class
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:179:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick.rb:1:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/shared/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick.rb:12:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/releases/20160622173816/config/application.rb:9:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/releases/20160622173816/Rakefile:1:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     /home/deploy/apps/razborki/releases/20160622173816/Rakefile:5:in `(root)'
DEBUG[eff60d47]     (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I fix it?

This is my  Gemfile.lock                                              :

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/capistrano/sshkit.git
  revision: 9027b0dcd0b25a762d90ab154ca44fca9fb57e00
  specs:
    sshkit (1.5.1)
      colorize
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git
  revision: 2f2c0fb7a25ece68fd3a9eec7b9026848e66fa4f
  specs:
    elasticsearch-model (0.1.6)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 0.4)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (0.1.6)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git
  revision: db17aa0145164095b2b21f83f1ef7ccf91b9ea54
  specs:
    jquery-datatables-rails (3.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1)
      sass-rails

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    aasm (4.0.0)
    actionmailer (4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.11)
      activerecord (>= 2.2)
    activesupport (4.1.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    ansi (1.4.3)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    ast (2.3.0)
    authlogic (3.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      request_store (~> 1.0.5)
    autoprefixer-rails (3.1.2.20141016)
      execjs
    bootstrap_form (2.3.0)
    buftok (0.2.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capistrano (3.2.1)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.0.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano3-puma (0.8.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      puma (>= 2.6)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    colorize (0.7.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.0-java)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    dalli (2.7.1)
    database_cleaner (1.4.1)
    descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    elasticsearch (1.0.8)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.7)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.7)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.7)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.7)
      faraday
      multi_json
    equalizer (0.0.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.8.9)
      multipart-post (~> 1.2.0)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    ffi (1.9.3-java)
    ffi-compiler (0.1.3)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
      rake
    figaro (1.1.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    font-awesome-rails (4.2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    geocoder (1.2.1)
    gibberish (1.4.0)
    gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 5.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    hashie (3.4.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hirb (0.7.1)
    html2haml (2.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (~> 4.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    http (0.5.0)
      http_parser.rb
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0-java)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jdbc-mysql (5.1.33)
    jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    jquery_mobile_rails (1.4.5)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    jruby-memcache-client (1.7.2)
    json (1.8.3)
    json (1.8.3-java)
    kaminari (0.16.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    launchy (2.4.2-java)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      spoon (~> 0.0.1)
    letter_opener (1.2.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.7)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    memoizable (0.4.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.6.0)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.17)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-java)
    parser (2.3.1.2)
      ast (~> 2.2)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    protected_attributes (1.0.7)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.1, < 5.0)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry (0.10.3-java)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      spoon (~> 0.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    puma (2.12.2)
    puma (2.12.2-java)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.8)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      actionview (= 4.1.8)
      activemodel (= 4.1.8)
      activerecord (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.8)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (4.0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    rails-observers (0.1.2)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    railties (4.1.8)
      actionpack (= 4.1.8)
      activesupport (= 4.1.8)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.1.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    redis (3.2.2)
    redis-namespace (1.5.1)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    request_store (1.0.5)
    rmagick (2.13.4)
    rmagick4j (0.3.8)
    rspec-core (3.2.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-support (3.2.2)
    rubocop (0.40.0)
      parser (>= 2.3.1.0, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    ruby_parser (3.7.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    scrypt (1.2.1)
      ffi-compiler (>= 0.0.2)
      rake
    searchkick (1.3.0)
      activemodel
      elasticsearch (>= 1)
      hashie
    sexp_processor (4.6.0)
    sidekiq (4.1.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    simple_oauth (0.2.0)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sitemap_generator (5.0.5)
      builder
    slop (3.6.0)
    smarter_csv (1.0.19)
    spoon (0.0.4)
      ffi
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    therubyrhino (2.0.4)
      therubyrhino_jar (>= 1.7.3)
    therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    thread_safe (0.3.5-java)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    tinymce-rails (4.0.19)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
    turn (0.8.3)
      ansi
    twitter (5.5.1)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      buftok (~> 0.2.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0.9)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      http (~> 0.5.0)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      memoizable (~> 0.4.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unicode-display_width (1.0.5)
    whenever (0.9.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)

PLATFORMS
  java
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aasm
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter
  authlogic
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootstrap_form
  capistrano (~> 3.2.0)
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rbenv
  capistrano3-puma
  carrierwave (~> 0.10.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  dalli (~> 2.7.1)
  database_cleaner
  elasticsearch-model!
  elasticsearch-rails!
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails
  figaro
  font-awesome-rails
  geocoder
  gibberish
  gmaps4rails (= 2.1.2)
  haml-rails (~> 0.9)
  hirb
  jdbc-mysql
  jquery-datatables-rails!
  jquery-fileupload-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  jquery_mobile_rails
  jruby-memcache-client
  kaminari (~> 0.16.2)
  letter_opener
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.15)
  protected_attributes
  pry-rails
  puma
  quiet_assets
  rails (~> 4.1)
  rails-i18n (~> 4.0.0)
  rails-observers
  rake (>= 10.0.0)
  redis-namespace
  remotipart (~> 1.2)
  rmagick
  rmagick4j
  rspec-rails
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.2)
  scrypt
  searchkick
  sidekiq
  sinatra
  sitemap_generator
  smarter_csv
  sshkit (~> 1.3)!
  therubyracer
  therubyrhino
  tinymce-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  turn (~> 0.8.3)
  twitter
  uglifier (>= 2.5.0)
  whenever

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

searchkick 1.3.0

ruby-2.1.0

rails-4.1.8

Comment: Looks like 2 gems are using the same constant name `DEFAULT_BOUNDARY` (one of them being faraday gem). Another option would be that you have 2 versions of faraday gem. Could you please add your `Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I added it

Answer (score 0):

The warning is caused by `faraday` gem versions earlier than `0.9.0rc1`. [Looks like](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/233) the problem is Ruby `1.8.7` specific and does not occur in Ruby `> 1.9`. It has been fixed in newer version of the gem.

So, you have two options:

1. Update your faraday gem.
2. Upgrade to Ruby 1.9 or later.

Comment: But I'm using Ruby 2.1.0

Comment: Then, you only have one option. Update your gem to the latest version.